# Hibernate and testcontainers

Tags: java, hibernate, testcontainers

I need to run my tests in docker containers. I have Testcontainers lib for this. Besides that I use hibernate. Also, I use Flyway to run some initial SQL scripts. I'm new in Testcontainers and Hibernate and don't understand why I get "Relation not found exception". This is how my app organized:

Abstract test for initializing container:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractIT.DockerPostgreDataSourceInitializer.class)
@Testcontainers
public class AbstractIT {

    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreDBContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<> 
    ("postgres:12.2");

    static {
        postgreDBContainer.start();
    }

    public static class DockerPostgreDataSourceInitializer implements 
        ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    applicationContext,
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreDBContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreDBContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreDBContainer.getPassword()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My test for "create" function that extends abstract AbstractIT:

```
@SpringBootTest
class JdbcGroupDaoTest extends AbstractIT {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcGroupDao jdbcGroupDao;

    @Test
    void create() throws Exception {
        jdbcGroupDao.setFactory(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("university-test"));
        Group group = new Group("Test group");
        Group expected = new Group(1L, "Test group");
        Group actual = jdbcGroupDao.save(group);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Class under test:

```
@Component
public class JdbcGroupDao extends JdbcAbstractDao<Group, Long> implements GroupDao {
    private EntityManagerFactory factory ;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcGroupDao.class);

@Override
public void setFactory(EntityManagerFactory factory){
    this.factory = factory;
}

@Override
protected Group create(Group group) {
    if(factory==null){
        factory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("university");
    }
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(group);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    entityManager.flush();
    factory.close();
    return group;
}
```

My config file for Hibernate:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="university">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/university" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="university-test">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
value="org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8:///university"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The error message:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "groups" does not exist
```

I have two persistence units here because this is the only way I found to prevent hibernate from altering data in real DB. I believe this is the main reason why I got my error. Though I don't know how to fix it.
If you need more info about my code, feel free to ask, I will add whatever you need into my post.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Flyway init. sql file. (added code related to "groups" only):

```
create table groups
(
    id    serial
        constraint groups_pkey
            primary key,
    title varchar(100)
);
alter table groups
    add constraint uq_groups_title UNIQUE
        (
         title
            );
```

Comment: I think the issue is that your Flyway initializer does not work for your integration tests. Could you add the initializer code and the part, where the initializer is invoked? You can validate this hypothesis by debugging your test: add a breakpoint to the test code and check if the necessary tables exist in the database in the container at this point using psql client for example.

Comment: @yuppie-flu, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by Flyway initializer, but I added a SQL file that creates my DB.

Comment: Also, I wanted to add that my other tests (of methods that do not include hibernate) run correctly with Testcontainers.

Comment: Yep, it was a wrong idea about the flyway. Now I see, that your `university-test` persistence unit starts another postgres container (with 9.8.6 version) and does not use the original one created in `AbstractIT`. This article might be useful https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-testcontainers-a-perfect-match-for-your-tests/ (You need something similar to `Option 2` there).

Comment: Also, I'm not an expert with hibernate, but it seems like the usage of `persistence.xml` is kind of deprecated in recent versions of Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-use-traditional-persistence-xml So you can try to get rid of it completely and configure everything using spring beans and spring boot application properties.

Comment: @yuppie-flu, you were absolutely right when said that my approach with persistence xml was deprecated. I used this tutorial https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/hibernate-configuration-example/ and now everything works fine. Thank you very much for your help. If you want, you can add your comment as the answer and I will accept it. Thank you again!